# Is it possible to write a func, method, struct, extension, class that returns a HStack of Text Views?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I would like to be able to say I need a HStack of so mamy Text Views and have them appear in my body of Content View.
The closest I got is this:
I have a file called TextView.swift with the following code:

```
import SwiftUI
 
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
 
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle
 
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
 
        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle)
        textView.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
 
        return textView
    }
 
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle)
     }
  }
// In content view:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var message = "this is my message in a bottle"
    @State private var textStyle = UIFont.TextStyle.body
    
    var body: some View {
        TextView(text: $message, textStyle: $textStyle)
            .padding(.horizontal)
    }    
}
```

Instead of a Text View I would like to have an HStack with 15 Text Views inside it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply write a function to return the desired view.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let numberOfTextViews = 15

    func getTextViews() -> some View {
        return HStack {
            ForEach(0..<self.numberOfTextViews, id: \.self) {
                index in
                Text("this is item \(index)")
                    .background(index % 2 == 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Blue)
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        self.getTextViews()
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad Rahchamani it works great. There is just a small typo ForEach(0..<self.numberOfTextView, id: \.self)  should be ForEach(0..<self.numberOfTextViews, id: \.self) I have another question: How would you go to make the background colour of  some of the text Views change?

Comment: Thanks  Mohammad Rahchamani, that is good for making 1 red and the next blue. Here is another challenge: I have 255 tiles ie a grid 15x15 and I need to be able to decide the colour of tiles at given positions. I declared these variables:
    let purple = Color.purple
    let pink = Color.pink    
    let green = Color.green
       let blue = Color.blue    
    let greenPos = [3,11,36,38,45,52]
    let bluePos = [20,24,76,80,64,88,136,140,144,148,200,204]
    let redPos = [0,7,14,105,119,210,217,224]
    let purplePos = [16,28,32,42,48,56,64,70,154,160] Is it possible or am I dreaming?

Comment: you can add a function to return the desired background based on your conditions.
you should post another question and I'll be more than happy to help you with the code.